# UIToolbar buttons turned grey if using the button in the opposite bar button item

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a navigation bar with a view in the right bar button item.
This view contains a UIToolbar with 2 UIBarButtonItem (that's why i'm using a view and a UIToolbar)

[image: views hierarchy]

When i build the app, the bar displays with all the buttons with the same color (expected behavior) :

[image: navigation bar buttons at the start]

But if i'm using the button in the left bar button item (the bookmark one, then coming back), the buttons in the UIToolbar in the right bar button item turn grey :

[image: navigation bar buttons turned grey]

I'm setting the tintColor in IB and also globally :

```
// Colors is an enum returning UIColor for all colors i need in the app

UIToolbar.appearance().tintColor = Colors.orange.uicolor
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = Colors.orange.uicolor
```

**EDIT:**

- The buttons are still usable with the segues associated to them, even after the color turned to grey, they are not disabled.
- No error in the console
- If i'm using the right buttons and come back, they keep the orange color

Why are they turning grey, and how can I avoid that ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Also are the grey buttons usable: grey could mean they have been disabled.

Comment: Yes, sorry i didn't write about that, i linked a segue to each button and yes they are still usable even after turned to grey. It seems it's only a matter of color changing.

Comment: I noticed in another post that this can happen if you pop the target controller before it has finished its original push animation. e.g. Calling pop inside `viewDidLoad` or `view(Will/Did)Appear`. Any chance this could be happening?

Comment: I don't think so, i'm only using the navigation bar standard behavior in IB, i didn't add anything in any `view*` functions.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same problem. The toolbar button turns grey, when the view reappears after dismissing a pushed viewcontroller.